# Using Arraylist in Mule to query Salesforce

Tags: java, salesforce, mule, esb

We are trying to query Salesforce with an ArrayList in the where statement.

Below is is the error we ran into when we tried using the ArrayList in the where clause.

Query we used against Salesforce:

```sql
Select Id,Billing_Number__c from Call_Log__c where Id in #[flowVars.successlist]
```

`successlist` contains the values `['a1o90000001msXwAAI', 'a1o90000001msXxAAI']`.

Error Message:

> Message: Failed to invoke query. Message payload is of type: ArrayList

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use `ArrayList`s as parameters in Salesforce (or Database) queries. You'll have to create the query dynamically with a script component.

Try this:

```xml
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
<![CDATA[def sb = new StringBuilder()
sb.append('Select Id,Billing_Number__c from Call_Log__c')
if (flowVars.successlist != null && !flowVars.successlist.empty) {
    sb.append(' where Id in (\'')
    for (i in 0 .. flowVars.size()) {
        if (i > 0) sb.append('\',\'')
        sb.append(flowVars.successlist[i])
    }
    sb.append('\')')
}
flowVars.query = sb.toString()]]>
        </scripting:script>  
        <sfdc:query query="#[flowVars.query]" doc:name="Salesforce - Query"/>
```

If you were using a Database, you would have to set the query type as dynamic:

```xml
        <db:select doc:name="Database">
            <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[#[flowVars.query]]]></db:dynamic-query>
        </db:select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much the quick help!

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question too. Thank you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957371/insert-arraylist-in-database-in-mule

Answer (score 0):

We have used a Java function string.join to convert the list as shown below:

```
SELECT id  FROM User where Id  in   (#["'" + String.join("','", flowVars.fvCreatedbyIdList) + "'"])
```