# Insert Arraylist in Database in Mule

Tags: arraylist, mule, esb

I am trying to insert the contents of an `ArrayList` to a SQL Server database using Mule ESB. The `ArrayList` looks like

```
[
    {Id=a1o90000001muvWAAQ, Billing_Number__c=1000005, type=Call_Log__c}, 
    {Id=a1o90000001muvXAAQ, Billing_Number__c=1000006, type=Call_Log__c}
]
```

How should I insert this into the database in an optimized way?

My mule flow is as below.

```
<sfdc:query config-ref="Salesforce__Basic_authentication" query="#[flowVars.query]" 
        doc:name="Salesforce"/>
<set-variable variableName="result" value="#[new java.util.ArrayList()]" 
        doc:name="Variable"/>
<foreach doc:name="For Each">
    <set-variable variableName="itrresult" value="#result.add(message.payload)]" 
            doc:name="Variable"/>
</foreach>
<splitter expression="#[flowVars.result]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
<logger message="#[payload['Id']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

`#[payload['Id']]` gives me the Id LoggerMessageProcessor: a1o90000001mzgzAAA in log.

I am not sure what i am doing is the right way though. I am just on the beginning of the learning curve in Mule.

Comment: Is logging the Ids a requirement? Or you're doing it just for debug purposes?

Comment: @ericbn you are right. I am doing it for debugging purpose. The actual requirement is to insert in SQL db

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a Splitter or the Foreach scope. The Database connector has a [bulk mode](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/35X/Database+Connector#DatabaseConnector-optional) that makes the connector accept a collection as payload.

> Enable to submit collections of data with one query, [...]. Enabling bulk mode improves the performance of your applications as it reduces the number of individual query executions. Bulk mode requires a parameterized query with at least one parameter.

Enable it with `bulkMode="true"` in an insert, update or delete operation.

**EDIT:** Use this right after your Salesforce Query component:

```xml
    <sfdc:query config-ref="" query="#[flowVars.query]" doc:name="Salesforce"/>
    <db:insert config-ref="" bulkMode="true" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query>
            <![CDATA[INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, BILLING_NUMBER__C, TYPE)  
            VALUES (#[payload.Id], #[payload.Billing_Number__c], #[payload.type]);]]>
        </db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>
```

The payload returned by the Database Insert component is an array with the number of rows changed for each query executed. In your case, an array of one's with the size of how many items the Salesforce Query component returned, like `[1, 1, 1, ...]`.

If you still need to log, do this:

```xml
    <sfdc:query config-ref="" query="#[flowVars.query]" doc:name="Salesforce"/>
    <foreach doc:name="For Each">
       <logger message="#[payload.Id]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </foreach>
    <db:insert config-ref="" bulkMode="true" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><!-- the query --></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>
```

Or this:

```xml
    <sfdc:query config-ref="" query="#[flowVars.query]" doc:name="Salesforce"/>
    <foreach doc:name="For Each">
       <logger message="#[payload.Id]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <db:insert config-ref="" doc:name="Database"><!-- bulkMode disabled -->
            <db:parameterized-query><!-- the query --></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:insert>
    </foreach>
```

Comment: thanks @ericbn - but If i try to access the arraylist like what you have mentioned #[payload.Id]. I see only null value in that.

Comment: What's inside your ArrayList? Instances of HashMap? The Database component will iterate each of your instances, so `#[payload.Id]` is valid in the query if `#[payload[0].Id]` is valid in the payload that the component receives.

Comment: I'm not sure if the `;` at the end of the query is required. It may be. Try adding it if you're facing problems.

Comment: I was itching to test this and confirm back to you - this is the earliest i could login mule again. Actually I am querying Salesforce so the payload i get is consumer iterator i converted into an arraylist then split it and used in the Insert DB statement. If i try not to split the arraylist and use #[payload[0].Id] i get an error message as below Execution of the expression "payload[0].Id" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: ConsumerIterator

Comment: @Anandmagesh, can you please update your question posting the code of this flow you have?

Comment: i have updated the question with flow. Instead of the logger i was using my DB connection to insert the Id value.

Comment: Hi Eric do you think yo ucan help answer this question .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132116/db-lookup-in-mule-not-accepting-integrated-authentication

Answer (score 1):

Use splitter to split your array and insert individually:

```
    <splitter expression="#[payload]" />
    <db:insert config-ref="Config" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into xx(Id, Billing_Number__c, type) values('#[payload['Id']]','#[payload['Billing_Number__c']]','#[payload['type']]');]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>
```

Comment: So the insert operation will be performed as an one time operation or for each splitter value insert will happen separately ? What if i  use it in a batch commit ?

Comment: The splitter will split your message into multiple messages, each one have a payload of one array item. All will be executed in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the `ArrayList` using a `for`, inserting values one by one using `db:dynamic-query`.

Answer (score 0):

Mule support the bulk mode to insert a collection of data. I prefer the `db:in-param` Element with labels within the SQL statement. Configuration has been tested with Mule 3.8.5.

```
<db:insert config-ref="databaseConfiguration" bulkMode="true" doc:name="Database">
    <db:parameterized-query>
    <![CDATA[INSERT INTO T_ORDER (ORDER_NO,CUSTOMER_NO) VALUES (:orderNo, :customerNo)]]>
    </db:parameterized-query>
    <db:in-param name="orderNo"  value="#[payload.orderNo]" />
    <db:in-param name="customerNo"  value="#[payload.customerNo]" />
</db:insert>
```

The bulk mode offers a much better performance. Make sure your DBMS is configured correctly for this use case.

Collection with huge entries can be partioned, for example to sub collection of 100 entries, before calling the `db:insert` component.

```
<!-- Sample: Collection with 1.000 entries -->
<!-- will be chunked into sub collections with 100 entries -->
<foreach batchSize="100" />
```