# DB Lookup in Mule - Not accepting Integrated Authentication

Tags: mule, esb, datamapper

We are trying to use DB lookup in Mule data mapper in our project, We are able to validate successful connection without integrated authentication even though when we have added sqljdbc_auth.dll in classpath as well as in the referenced library we are not able to have integrated authentication.

Any pointers to resolve this issue will be helpful. Thanks! [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding if this will be helpful to any of those who came across this issue -  I finally made it working by adding JTDS drivers in the library and the below JTDS  file for integrated authentication jtds-1.2.7-dist\x64\SSO